# Xpath and concat elements and text

Tags: xml, xpath

Please give me a helping hand. I tried to concat the elements `<forename>`  from different elements with different types. The result should be 
From Mustermann to Kraft

```
<head>
              <persName type="sender" xml:id="ID.1">
                <forename>Max</forename>
                <surname>Mustermann</surname>
              </persName>
              <persName type="adresser" xml:id="ID.30">
                <forename>Susi</forename>
                <surname>Kraft</surname>
              </persName>
            </head>
```

I tried many different styles and the problem is that I am not able to navigate in the concat function. As far as I know concat is working fine with strings in the same space. But look at this also not possible. What is my mistake and do you have a solution for that. And please I need in XPATH not XSLT. This is also not working.:

```
//persName/concat( "This " , "is " , "a " , "test ", surename)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
concat('From ',
       /head/persName[@type="sender"]/surname,
       ' to ',
       /head/persName[@type="adresser"]/surname)
```

Tested in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh).

Comment: well done this was easy for you or ? anyway, thank you, and if i have more then those 2 i mean i have more then 1 head element and i want do move thode things in a loop, yes it is a rookie question, but would be so kind again and help me out ?

Comment: If you have another question, ask it as a new question, not as a comment. There are no loops in XPath 1.0.