# XPath concat navigation with more then one element

Tags: xml, xpath, concatenation

OK, thanks to Choroba, for the helping hand. I have another question, when i have more then one head element, like this

```
<test>
    <head>
        <persName type="sender" xml:id="ID.1">
            <forename>Max</forename>
            <surname>Mustermann</surname>
        </persName>
        <persName type="adresser" xml:id="ID.30">
            <forename>Susi</forename>
            <surname>Kraft</surname>
        </persName>
    </head>
    <head>
        <persName type="sender" xml:id="ID.2">
            <forename>Max1</forename>
            <surname>Mustermann1</surname>
        </persName>
        <persName type="adresser" xml:id="ID.31">
            <forename>Susi</forename>
            <surname>Kraft1</surname>
        </persName>
    </head>
    <head>
        <persName type="sender" xml:id="ID.3">
            <forename>Max1</forename>
            <surname>Mustermann2</surname>
        </persName>
        <persName type="adresser" xml:id="ID.32">
            <forename>Susi</forename>
            <surname>Kraft2</surname>
        </persName>
    </head>
</test>
```

then my XPATH Query is returning me From To without the results. I think i have to navigate with the XPath axes, but how..

```
concat('From ',
descendant-or-self::head/persName[@type="sender"]/surname,
' to ',
descendant-or-self::head/persName[@type="adresser"]/surname)
```

i also got an error message like this, i am working with oxygen
"A sequence of more then one item is not allowed as the second argument of concat"

Comment: The xpath, `descendant-or-self::head/persName[@type="sender"]/surname`, which is the 2nd parameter in `concat()` returns 3 values(from the input XML you've provided); but each parameter of `concat()` function must not have more than 1 value. Hence the error. The same applies to the 4th parameter.

Comment: What output do you expect? Adding a link to the previous question would be handy, too.

Comment: OK, i expect that.

sender Mustermann adresser Kraft
sender Mustermann1 adresser Kraft1
sender Mustermann2 adresser Kraft2

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988090/xpath-and-concat-elements-and-text

Comment: ok, got it solved it, the solution is in the combination of concat and the navigation of the axes..

Answer (score 0):

This is working in my example,

```
//persName[@type="creator"]/concat("von ", surname , " to " ,
ancestor::head/persName[@type="addressee"]/surname)
```

have a good time and a happy new year